# What are the advantages of hyperledger-fabric over private ethereum network?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, ethereum, hyperledger

What are the advantages of hyperledger-fabric compared to a private Ethereum network? According to what I've read, Ethereum seems to be more like a general-purpose blockchain network whereas hyperledger-fabric can be more business-oriented but so far the features offering that advantage are not very clear to me.

Comment: The future of Hyperledger looks uncertain with its key contributor away, so the advantage of Ethereum is that it is not dead https://www.coindesk.com/ibm-blockchain-revenue-misses-job-cuts-sources

Comment: That's not true. Please check this link
[link](https://www.ledgerinsights.com/ibm-blockchain-withdrawal-false/)

Well regarding the advantages I can say the consensus mechanism is different, there is no cryptocurrency concept in fabric. It is designed to meet the need of an enterprise blockchain system.

Answer (score 0):

> - Fabric is a Hyperledger project. It is an enterprise-grade distributed ledger that allows the development blockchain solutions
>   with a modular architecture. It has a permissioned architecture,
>   support modularization, pluggable consensus, and supports smart
>   contracts(aka ‘Chaincode’ in case of Hyperledger Fabric).
> - Various functions in the fabric are pluggable, and it also allows the use of any language to develop smart contracts. This functionality
>   is possible because it is based on container technology (Docker),
>   which can host any language.
> - As of now smart-contract in the blockchain run on an order-execute environment where the consensus protocol validate and order
>   transactions and broadcasts it to all the peer nodes in the network,
>   each peer node then sequentially executes the transaction. Most
>   blockchains today run on this order-execute blockchain environment.
>   The issue in this order-execute environment is that the smart contract
>   running here needs to be deterministic otherwise a consensus might
>   never be reached. To solve this issue, smart contracts have been
>   written in non-standard languages like Solidity with which the
>   non-deterministic operations are eliminated. However, this hinders
>   blockchain large scale adoption as smart contracts need to be written
>   in an altogether new language and it may lead to programming errors.
>   Moreover, as all transactions are only executed sequentially,
>   performance and scale are limited.
>
>   As Fabric eliminates the non-determinism issue, it has become the
>   first blockchain to enable the use of standard programming languages
>   to write smart contracts. In the 1.1.0 release, the smart contracts
>   will be written in either Node.js or Go; in the subsequent releases it
>   is envisioned that the platform will support other popular programming
>   languages like Java.
> - As widely known, the public blockchain network runs on Proof-of-Work concept and the transactions are executed on every node. Every
>   transaction and code that is implemented is visible to every node in
>   the network. This means neither the smart contract stays confidential
>   nor the transaction data which is processed. This means we have
>   exchanged the privacy of the contract and data for the public
>   consensus concept of PoW.
>
>   This lack of privacy is problematic for businesses. For example, in a supply chain business, some partners might be offered additional
>   discounts as a means of solidifying business. If everyone in the
>   network is able to see the contract and transaction, it won’t be
>   possible to do business – everyone will ask for the discounted rates!
>
>   Hyperledger Fabric as a permissioned blockchain offers privacy and confidentiality through its channel architecture. With Fabric, one can
>   establish a “channel” between the subset of participants who should be
>   granted the right to access a set of transactions. Like a network
>   overlay, only the nodes that participate in a channel have the access
>   to the chaincode (smart contract) and transaction data. This helps to
>   preserve confidentiality and privacy and builds trust in the network.
>   To enhance the privacy and confidentiality aspect, Fabric is offering
>   support to keep the data private and is developing zero knowledge
>   proofs (ZKP).